# How to use sqlite in ios 7?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios7

How to use sqlite in ios 7? I'm trying to use code ios 6 and it does not work in ios 7

### **UPDATE!**

I export a database, to desktop, change name and drag and drop to xcode
[image]
Add the code:

```
// SQLite
// Conexion DB
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

_databasePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ambisi_test.sqlite"];
[self loadDB];
// --> End SQLite



-(void)loadDB{
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *writableDBPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ambisi_test.sqlite"];

BOOL exito = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if(exito) return;

NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ambisi_test.sqlite"];

BOOL exit = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];

if(!exit) NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
```

}

```
- (void) clickFavorites{

sqlite3 *database = NULL;
sqlite3_stmt *sentencia = NULL;

// Si la BD se ha abierto bien
if(sqlite3_open([appDelegate.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK){
    // Genero la query
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO estaciones (\"id_number\", \"name\",\"addres\",\"latitude\",\"longitude\") VALUES (\"%i\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%f\",\"%f\")", self.modelAnnotation.number, self.modelAnnotation.name,self.modelAnnotation.address, self.modelAnnotation.lat,self.modelAnnotation.lng];
    NSLog(@"%@",sql);
    // Si esta no contien errores
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &sentencia, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){

        // Si la estación no existe ya como favorita, la almacenaré, o en el caso contrario la elimnaré
        if(![self isFavoriteWithIdStation:self.modelAnnotation.number database:database]){
            // Insisto hasta que se inserte
            if (sqlite3_step(sentencia) != SQLITE_DONE){
                 NSLog(@"Error in INSERT step: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }else{
                // Ademas de cambiarle la imagen
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"quitar-favorito"];
                [_button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }

        }else{ // La elimino de favoritas
            // Genero la query
            NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM estaciones WHERE id_number = \"%i\"",self.modelAnnotation.number];
            // Si esta no contien errores
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &sentencia, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
                // Insisto hasta que se inserte
                if (sqlite3_step(sentencia) != SQLITE_DONE){
                    NSLog(@"Error in DELETE step: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }else{
                    // Ademas de cambiarle la imagen
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addfav"];
                    [_button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error making INSERT: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sentencia);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Doesn't open Database: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

```
- (BOOL) isFavoriteWithIdStation:(int) idStation database:(sqlite3 *)db{

sqlite3_stmt *sentencia = NULL;
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id_number FROM estaciones"];
NSLog(@"%i",idStation);
NSString * ide = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",idStation];
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &sentencia, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
    while(sqlite3_step(sentencia) == SQLITE_ROW){
        NSLog(@"%i",idStation);
        NSString *number = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sentencia, 0)];
        //NSString *id_tutorialString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
        if([number isEqualToString:ide]){
            NSLog(@"NUMBER:%@",number);
            NSLog(@"NUMBER:%i",idStation);
            sqlite3_finalize(sentencia);
            return YES;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Error en el condicional");
        }

    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"Error making SELCET: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
sqlite3_finalize(sentencia);

return NO;
```

}

The error is triggered in the 
NSLog (@ "Error making INSERT:% s", sqlite3_errmsg (database));
and the response has been making INSERT Error: **file is encrypted or is not a database**

I've also tried to recreate the DB and import it several times, but still with the same error..

In the iOS simulator iOS 6 if it works but in iOS7 is not working ... is rare, someone tried to use SQLite in iOS7? ..

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: And what does sqlite3_errmsg return??

Comment: No returns error, triggers the NSLog cited in the description

Comment: I have used NSLog (@ "Error making INSERT:% s", sqlite3_errmsg (database));, and the response has been making INSERT Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

Comment: What the message says.  I'm guessing you've somehow bungled the file path.

Comment: Hint:  When prepare came back with a bad return code, that indicated an error.

Comment: The error indicates --> file is encrypted or is not a database, I modified the question adding  all code for conexion, but I repeat saying that ios6 simulator works and that of ios7 not

Comment: NSLog the path of the DB file, just before you open it.  And where did "ambisi_test.sqlite" come from?  How was it created?

Comment: The path is -->> /Users/Lito/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/6A8D996E-A813-43CB-AF84-9E22CCF16147/Library/ambisi.sqlite <--, and I cretate a database with Firefox sqlite plugin.. Create database, and export database to desktop, change ambisi.sql for ambisi.sqlite, and drag and drop to xcode and check the three checkbox to corerct add ing file

Comment: And how do you get it out of the bundle and into the working directory?

Comment: (Open a terminal window, cd to the above location, start sqlite3, and see if it recognizes your DB file.)

Comment: In the path yes exists a file ambisi.sqlite, what happens here?

Comment: I didn't ask that. I asked how it got there from the bundle, and then suggested you examine it with the sqlite3 OSx command.

Comment: Arrived typing the path, to see if he was there, and then type the command sqlite3 and allows me to send queries, but being empty I can not see anything, you were referring to this action?, Forgive me but my English is not very good!

Comment: How could it be empty, if you pre-created it?  Didn't you load the DB with some values?  (If not, what was the point of pre-creating it?)

Comment: Sorry I have created a table called stations, stations has five attributes, id, name, address, latitude, longitude .. so the table does not have are any stored item

Comment: But when you open the DB file with sqlite3 and issue, say, `.tables`, do you see your tables?

Comment: No, with the command .tables shows nothing, -->>iMac-de-Hipolito:Library Lito$ sqlite3 -->>
SQLite version 3.7.12 2012-04-03 19:43:07 -->>
Enter ".help" for instructions -->>
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";" -->>
sqlite> .tables -->>
sqlite>     -->> is empty.. oouuh!!

Comment: Specify your file name when you start sqlite3.

Comment: And use this path:  /Users/Lito/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/6A8D996E-A813-43CB-AF84-9E22CCF16147/Library/ambis‌​i.sqlite

Comment: `cd  /Users/Lito/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0-64/Applications/6A8D996E-A813-43CB-AF84-9E22CCF16147/Library/`, then `sqlite3 ambisi.sqlite`.

Comment: iMac-de-Hipolito:Library Lito$ sqlite3 ambisi.sqlite  -->>
SQLite version 3.7.12 2012-04-03 19:43:07 -->>
Enter ".help" for instructions -->>
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";" -->>
sqlite> .tables  -->>
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database -->>
sqlite> SELECT * FROM estaciones; -->>
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database -->>
sqlite>   ..... The same mistake as in the simulator!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The main mistake I committed in exporting the database using firefox plugin ..

The solution is to store the desired location without export, at the time of the creation of the database ..

I hope if someone happens to have the same, here is the solution, thanks for your interest for **@Rob** and **@Hot Licks**..

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering what you meant by "exporting" it.  If you want to pre-create your DB use `sqlite3` or a tool like "SQLite Expert" (which I think is only available on Windows, but there must be others for OSx).

Answer (score 2):

You should look at error codes.

Thus, the line that says:

```
NSLog(@"Error making INSERT");
```

should say:

```
NSLog(@"Error making INSERT: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Likewise the line that says:

```
NSLog(@"Error la SELECT");
```

should say:

```
NSLog(@"Error la SELECT: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Only by looking at those error messages can you effectively diagnose the problem.

---

You report that it says: "file is encrypted or is not a database"

That suggests that your database has gotten corrupted somehow (assuming you never used encryption). You'll want to recreate it.

---

Unrelated to your broader problem, your code for the `INSERT` statement bears a line that says:

```
// Insisto hasta que se inserte
while(sqlite3_step(sentencia) == SQLITE_OK);
```

That should be:

```
if (sqlite3_step(sentencia) != SQLITE_DONE)
    NSLog(@"Error in INSERT step: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try what you recommended, and if I give it a ok worth :D