# Database returned error 26: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: ios, sqlite

I've created a database with Sqlite Manager and I export my database in my resources.
I've tried to recreate database directly in my project folder, I have the same error.
I don't understand why...
I've tried to open my database in my terminal and it doesn't possible to open my database, I have that :

```
sqlite> .tables
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I do all thing about this link, but nothing work for me
[How to use sqlite in ios 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993375/how-to-use-sqlite-in-ios-7)

```
int returnValue = (sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseOK, [selectSql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL));
```

This line give me 26 in my returnValue

```
-(id) initDatabase{

if (self = [super init]) {
    //Nom de la base de données
    self.databaseName = @"externalDB.sqlite";

    // Obtenir le chemins complet de la base de donées
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.databasePath);
}

return self;
}




-(NSArray*) selectALLArticle{
    sqlite3 *databaseOK=self.database;

    NSMutableArray* articles = [NSMutableArray new];

    if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &databaseOK) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString* selectSql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ART_TABLE"];

        sqlite3_stmt* statement = NULL;

        int returnValue = (sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseOK, [selectSql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL));

        NSLog(@"Database returned error %d: %s", sqlite3_errcode(databaseOK), sqlite3_errmsg(databaseOK));

        if(returnValue == SQLITE_OK){

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) { 
                Data* article = [Data new];
                article.ide = (NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
                article.title = (NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                article.chapo = (NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                article.link = (NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                article.linkImg = (NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
                article.pubDate = (NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
                article.creator = (NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
                article.description = (NSMutableString*)[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)];

                [articles addObject:article];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
    }

    sqlite3_close(databaseOK);

    return articles;

}
```

In my logcat I have :
Database returned error 26: file is encrypted or is not a database

With this line : `NSLog(@"Database returned error %d: %s", sqlite3_errcode(databaseOK), sqlite3_errmsg(databaseOK));`

When I create a database with SQLite Manager an other table was create, his name is : sqlite_sequence, what is that ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are bundling a stock database with your app, it will not be located in the Documents directory, but in the app bundle. While the specific error is not helpful, I suspect the database file is being created from scratch and then missing the table you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is a pain if you dont know what you're doing. I also had some problems with sqlite c functions but then i decided to use sqlite wrapper.

**FMDB and BWDB** are good and easy to use sqlite wrappers for objective c. I suggest you use one of those .

Note that BWDB is in a lynda.com tutorial (this one) and if you don't find it on the web...leave a comment and i'll upload it somewhere.

edit: the only place you can write stuff in your app is in your documents directory...so..it plain terms...if the db is not in your documents directory..is read-only..also..when you read/write to your db..the OS copies the db in the documents directory..and does all the reading and writing there so you can have a db in your app bundle but you can't edit that one...so you'll end up with 2 db.I had the same problem myself..and i fixed it by merging the 2 db when i updated the app

Answer (score 0):

Check sqlite version.If you are using sqlite *version 2* the error may occurs.
Change the sqlite *version 2* in to ***version 3***.
It works for me......